# Como criar um array de objetos com o useState do React

Tags: javascript, array, react-native

Estou tentando fazer o seguinte procedimento no React Native, com o Expo:

Tenho alguns dados armazenados no AsyncStorage do dispositivo. O código abaixo me retorna o seguinte resultado:

**CÓDIGO**

```
AsyncStorage.getAllKeys((err, keys) => {
     AsyncStorage.multiGet(keys, (err, stores) => {
        console.log(stores);
     });
  });
```

**RESULTADO**

```
Array [
 Array [
  "webservice_qng7ike7r",
  "{\"idWebservice\":\"qng7ike7r\",\"enderecoWebservice\":\"Endereço 2\",\"nomeWebservice\":\"Nome 2\"}",
 ],
 Array [
  "webservice_t572op73v",
  "{\"idWebservice\":\"t572op73v\",\"enderecoWebservice\":\"Endereço 1\",\"nomeWebservice\":\"Nome 1\"}",
 ],
 Array [
  "webservice_u6alr9qo8",
  "{\"idWebservice\":\"u6alr9qo8\",\"enderecoWebservice\":\"Endereço 3\",\"nomeWebservice\":\"Nome 3\"}",
 ],
]
```

Para poder montar um objeto apropriado, contendo apenas as informações necessárias do Webservice, estou fazendo o seguinte procedimento:

```
AsyncStorage.getAllKeys((err, keys) => {

     AsyncStorage.multiGet(keys, (err, stores) => {

        for (let i = 0; i < stores.length; i++) {

           const webserviceCorrente = stores[i];
           const objWebservice = JSON.parse(webserviceCorrente[1]);

           const data = {
              idWebservice: objWebservice.idWebservice,
              nomeWebservice: objWebservice.nomeWebservice,
              enderecoWebservice: objWebservice.enderecoWebservice,
           }

           console.log(data);
        }
     });
  });
```

Até aí, tudo certo. Ele me retorna o objeto desta maneira abaixo:

```
Object {
 "enderecoWebservice": "Endereço 1",
 "idWebservice": "t572op73v",
 "nomeWebservice": "Nome 1",
}
```

O que eu quero, é montar um array onde cada índice dele é um objeto contendo esses dados, dos 3 endereços cadastrados.

Estou tentando fazer dessa forma, mas sem sucesso:

**Declarando o State do array**

```
const [arrWebservices, setArrWebservices] = useState([]);
```

**Montando o array de objetos (sem sucesso)**

```
AsyncStorage.getAllKeys((err, keys) => {

     AsyncStorage.multiGet(keys, (err, stores) => {

        for (let i = 0; i < stores.length; i++) {

           const webserviceCorrente = stores[i];
           const objWebservice = JSON.parse(webserviceCorrente[1]);

           const data = {
              idWebservice: objWebservice.idWebservice,
              nomeWebservice: objWebservice.nomeWebservice,
              enderecoWebservice: objWebservice.enderecoWebservice,
           }

           setArrWebservices({ ...arrWebservices, data });
        }
     });
  });
```

Alguém pode me ajudar, por favor? Eu pesquisei pela internet mas não consegui encontrar uma solução.

Se precisarem de mais alguma informação, me avisem.

Obrigado desde já!

Comment: Para além de que é má ideia correr `setState` dentro de um loop síncrono, o tipo deve ser Array 
e não Object. Ou seja esses `{ ... }` deviam ser `[...]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O que procuras é uma Array e não um Objeto. Como estás a fazer estás a criar um objeto único com 3 chaves (idWebservice, nomeWebservice, enderecoWebservice) que estão sempre a ser re-escritas. Deves usar `[]` e não `{}`.

Ou seja: `setArrWebservices([ ...arrWebservices, data ]);`

Para além disso podes usar o `.map` e chamar esse hook só uma vez (e não uma vez a cada iteração do loop).

Sugestão:

```js
AsyncStorage.getAllKeys((err, keys) => {
  AsyncStorage.multiGet(keys, (err, stores) => {
    const webServices = stores.map(store => {
      const objWebservice = JSON.parse(store[1]);
      return {
        idWebservice: objWebservice.idWebservice,
        nomeWebservice: objWebservice.nomeWebservice,
        enderecoWebservice: objWebservice.enderecoWebservice,
      }
    });
    
    setArrWebservices(webServices);
  });
});
```

Comment: Obrigado pelo esclarecimento, Sergio! O seu exemplo deu certo =)
Só precisei fazer um ajuste, pois webserviceCorrente não estava definido, então fiz dessa forma:

const webServiceCorrente = store;
const objWebservice = JSON.parse(webServiceCorrente[1]);

De resto, o código ficou igual ao seu exemplo.

Abraços!

Comment: @LuanLuiz ótimo, corrigi também na resposta.